# Angular Material 2: Multiple mat-table sorting is working on first table only

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I have used Angular Material in my application and I have two `mat-table` with sorting on single component but my sorting is working only on first table

here is ts code

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) inventoryDataSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) inventoryDataPaginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild(MatSort) additionalDataSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) additionalDataPaginator: MatPaginator;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.inventoryDataSource.sort = this.inventoryDataSort;
    this.inventoryDataSource.paginator = this.inventoryDataPaginator;
    this.additionalDataSource.sort = this.additionalDataSort;
    this.additionalDataSource.paginator = this.additionalDataPaginator;
}
```

mat-table

```html
<mat-table #table1 [dataSource]="inventoryDataSource" matSort>
<mat-table #table2 [dataSource]="additionalDataSource" matSort>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selector in ViewChild queries DOM and it finds first math. Could you try change this part from

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) inventoryDataSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) inventoryDataPaginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild(MatSort) additionalDataSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) additionalDataPaginator: MatPaginator;
```

to

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) inventoryDataSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) inventoryDataPaginator: MatPaginator;

@ViewChild('table2', {read: MatSort}) additionalDataSort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('table2', {read: MatPaginator}) additionalDataPaginator: MatPaginator;
```

Comment: Still not working for me. I am having pagination and sort on all tables.

Comment: @ViewChild('table2', { read: MatPaginator }) paginatorUpcoming: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('table3', { read: MatPaginator }) paginatorExpired: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginatorGym: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('table2', { read: MatSort }) sortUpcoming: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('table3', { read: MatSort }) sortExpired: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sortGym: MatSort;

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001006/angular-material-distinct-mat-sort-on-multiple-tables/), but I will post it here also. It might help another poor soul.

Using Angular v.8.2.0.

I am assuming that all required attributes are used and correct (`mat-sort`, `mat-table`, `[dataSource]`, `matColumnDef`, `mat-sort-header`, etc).

I have a simple component with two sortable tables (I omitted the irrelevant code for brevity).

Each of the tables has an unique ref attribute in the template. For example:

```html
<table #table1>
<table #table2>
```

Then, in the component, I use the `@ViewChild` decorator for each of the sorters:

```js
@ViewChild('table1', { read: MatSort, static: true }) sort1: MatSort;
@ViewChild('table2', { read: MatSort, static: true }) sort2: MatSort;
```

The `read` property is very important here. Don't miss it!

Then (in `ngOnInit`), I assign the sorters to each table data source as shown in the offical docs:

```js
this.dataSource1.sort = this.sort1;
this.dataSource2.sort = this.sort2;
```