# Angular mat-table pagination not working, entire data is loaded on First page of mat-table

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular-flex-layout, angular-material-6

I have use Angular Material table, i have bind data source from ts file,but all the data is loaded on very first page, pagination is not working.I have two more table, which are on same page,same problem for other tables too.

I have tried

```
setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
```

and

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
}
```

HTML:

```
    <mat-table class="mt-4 table-container" fxFlex="100" [dataSource]="allUsers">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
        <mat-header-cell fxFlex="10" (click)="selectAllUsers()" *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkedAllUsers"></mat-checkbox>
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell fxFlex="10" *matCellDef="let element">
          <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked"></mat-checkbox>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
        <mat-header-cell fxFlex="25" *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell fxFlex="25" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
        <mat-header-cell fxFlex="25" *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell fxFlex="25" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell fxFlex="30" *matHeaderCellDef> Email </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell fxFlex="30" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell fxFlex="10" *matHeaderCellDef> Action </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell fxFlex="10" *matCellDef="let row; let i=index;">
          <button mat-icon-button class="viewButton" (click)="view(i, row.id, row.title, row.state, row.url, row.created_at, row.updated_at)">
            <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">remove_red_eye</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="allUsersColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: allUsersColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator #allUsersPaginatorr [pageSizeOptions]="[10,20,30]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

TS Code:

```
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

 allUsersColumns: string[] = ['checked', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 
'actions'];
allUsersDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
 allUsers: any[] = [
{ checked: false, firstName: 'Debi', lastName: 'Austin', email: 
 'd@gmail.com' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Jimmy', lastName: 'Williams', email: 
 'w@yahoo.in' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Randy', lastName: 'Waif', email: 
 'randy@gmail.com' },
  { checked: true, firstName: 'Chad', lastName: 'Spongla', email: 
   'c@redif.com' },
   { checked: false, firstName: 'Debi', lastName: 'Austin', email: 
  'd@gmail.com' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Jimmy', lastName: 'Williams', email: 
  'w@yahoo.in' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Randy', lastName: 'Waif', email: 
  'randy@gmail.com' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Chad', lastName: 'Spongla', email: 
 'c@redif.com' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Debi', lastName: 'Austin', email: 
 'd@gmail.com' },
    { checked: true, firstName: 'Jimmy', lastName: 'Williams', email: 
 'w@yahoo.in' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Chad', lastName: 'Spongla', email: 
 'c@redif.com' },
  { checked: false, firstName: 'Debi', lastName: 'Austin', email: 
 'd@gmail.com' },
  { checked: true, firstName: 'Jimmy', lastName: 'Williams', email: 
 'w@yahoo.in' }
 ];
ngOnInit() {
 this.allUsersDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.allUsers);
  this.allUsersDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If your `mat-paginator` is inside any `ngIf` conditioned block as shown in the below code, then the table shows all the data in the first page itself.

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
   <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ...
      ...
   </mat-table>
   <mat-paginator
         [length]="allUsers.length"
         [pageSize]="5"
         [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
   </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Solution 1:**
Move the `mat-paginator` code block outside of the `ngIf` conditioned block as shown below:

```
<div *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
   <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ...
      ...
   </mat-table>
</div>
<mat-paginator
         [length]="allUsers.length"
         [pageSize]="5"
         [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
</mat-paginator>
```

**Solution 2:**
Use `hidden` as alternative for `ngIf` directive as shown below:

```
<div [hidden]="!isDataLoaded">
   <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
      ...
      ...
   </mat-table>
   <mat-paginator
         [length]="allUsers.length"
         [pageSize]="5"
         [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
   </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Note:**
And of course, following mandatory steps for initializing mat-table data and mat-paginator

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.allUsers);
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

Happy Coding...Cheerzz

Comment: That was a great catch regarding `ngIf` I was struggling to find where I went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You should assign your data to the this.allUsersDataSource.**data**. Also ngAfterViewInit is necessary to relate the paginator with the table. Change your code

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.allUsersDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.allUsers);
  this.allUsersDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

with

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.allUsersDataSource.data = new MatTableDataSource(this.allUsers);
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.allUsersDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I will appreciate if you can upvote

Comment: Thanks for perfect solution.

Comment: Got it! But what if I don't wanna load my data in mat-table on page load. I want to load it when user clicks on any buttons?

Comment: I didn't try it but I think you can move "this.allUsersDataSource.data = new MatTableDataSource(this.allUsers);" to the place you would like.

Comment: I had same issue all data was showing intitally and pagination and sorting did not work, This solution works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The data source for the table should be `allUsersDataSource` not `allUsers`.

So change:

```
<mat-table class="mt-4 table-container" fxFlex="100" [dataSource]="allUsers">
                                                                     /\
```

To,

```
<mat-table class="mt-4 table-container" fxFlex="100" [dataSource]="allUsersDataSource">
```

<kbd>[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5brvt)</kbd>

Comment: Ohh great thank you so much..it work,But i have 5 mat-tabs on page it is working on first page as you suggested me to change datasource,but on next tab pagination is not working i have done same for table second

Comment: Do i have to create separate objects of paginator i.e @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator2: MatPaginator

Comment: hello Sir https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbgkht this is my url of my code, it is not working due to some issue,thanks in advance

Comment: @JayantBelekar Check out this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691186/angular-material-2-multiple-mat-table-sorting-is-working-on-first-table-only

Comment: Use different `MatPaginator` for different table

Comment: yes i did,ok i will see if there is anything else that is effecting it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the paginator was inside a div block with ngIf depending on the dataSource. So when in ngAfterViewInit() I call `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` this.paginator is not initialised. In my case the dataSource is initialised after the ngAfterViewInit is called due to the backend response time. The solution was to change ngIf with [hidden]. In that case the table and the paginator are not shown when there is no data, but this.paginator is initialised, so when the data comes in it will be set to the data dource properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should to initialize paginator like this:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) set matPaginator(paginator: MatPaginator) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = paginator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mat-table **inside its own component**, with ngAfterViewInit defined such as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-topics',
  templateUrl: './topics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topics.component.scss']
})
export class TopicsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

You can embed the mat-table component in the parent template (in this example with lazy loading) such as

```
<ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    <app-topics> </app-topics>
</ng-template>
```