# Mat data-table paginate and sort not working

Tags: html, angular-material, angular6

I have my HTML code like this:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="Model">
  <br>
  <mat-form-field class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
  </mat-form-field>


  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="StartTime">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> StartTime </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 15%"> {{row.call_start_time | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Duration">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Duration </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.call_total_duration}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="CallType">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CallType </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 5%"> {{row.call_type}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="CLI">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CLI </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 15%"> {{row.call_cli}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Campaign">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Campaign </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 20%"> {{row.call_service_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Agent">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Agent </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.call_agent_id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Disposition">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Disposition </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 20%"> {{row.call_end_type_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Remarks">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Remarks </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 20%"> {{row.call_remark}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="TransfferedTo">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 5%"> TransfferedTo </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 5%"> {{row.call_child_callnumber}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10, 25]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Question I referred:** [mat-sort not working on mat-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731798/mat-sort-not-working-on-mat-table)

I've referred some of the questions, but all of them are calling the service on ngOnInit(), but I need to call the service on the ngSubmit() method in my .ts file.

**Pagination and sorting are not working.** I believe there is a problem with my type script file and it looks like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CampaignService } from 'services/campaign.service';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';



export interface State {
  Name: string;
  Id: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logs',
  templateUrl: './logs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logs.component.css']
})
export class LogsComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['StartTime', 'Duration', 'CallType', 'CLI', 'Campaign' , 'Agent' , 'Disposition' , 'Remarks' , 'TransfferedTo'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private webService: CampaignService) {
  
  }


  FromDate: any;
  ToDate: any;
  Campaign: any;
  Agent: any;
  MobileNumber: any;
  stateCtrl = new FormControl();
  filteredStates: Observable<State[]>;
  Model: any;
  Data: any;
  Result: any;

  private _filterStates(value: string): State[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.Data.filter(state => state.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    //this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Result);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }



  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  onSubmit(data) {

    const deatails = JSON.stringify({
      FromDate: FromDate,
      ToDate: ToDate,
      Campaign: this.Campaign,
      Agent: data.Agent,
      MobileNumber: data.MobileNumber
    });


    this.webService.CallDetails(deatails)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.Model = response;
          this.Result = this.Model.log
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource( this.Result);
    
        },
        (error) => console.error(error)
      );
   
  }


}
```

Can anyone point out to me where I'm going wrong? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: check for my answer hope that helps you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328781/7772136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how I solved the problem just in case anybody need it:

```js
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
 
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }
    
 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();  
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['call_start_time', 'call_agent_login_id', 'call_cli', 'call_service_name', 'call_type', 'Play'];
 
 setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  
  onSubmit() {

    this.webService.CallDetails(deatails)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
        
          this.Model = response;
          this.Result = this.Model.log;
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Result);
        },
        
        (error) => console.error(error)
      );

  }
```

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="call_start_time" class="text-center">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> StartTime </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 25%"> {{row.call_start_time | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="call_agent_login_id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Agent </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.call_agent_login_id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="call_cli">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CLI </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width: 15%"> {{row.call_cli}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="call_service_name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Campaign </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="width:20px;"> {{row.call_service_name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  
  <ng-container matColumnDef="call_type">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="max-width:20px !important"> CallType </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.call_type}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Play">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Play</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">

      <button *ngIf="row.filepath" (click)="openDialog(row.filepath)" mat-stroked-button style="min-width:1%;" color="primary"><img src="../../assets/Images/play.png" /> </button>

      <button *ngIf="!row.filepath" mat-raised-button disabled style="min-width:1%;" color="primary"><img src="../../assets/Images/unavailable.png" /></button>
    </td>

  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
  </tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10, 25]"></mat-paginator>
```

I made sure that the **matColumDef** and the binding name are same for sorting to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is an Angular-thing where ViewChild doesn't catch elements with *ngIf in ngAfterViewInit.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8705#issuecomment-377266657

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added

`import {
   MatPaginatorModule,
   MatSortModule
} from '@angular/material';`

and

`@NgModule({
   exports: [
   MatPaginatorModule,
   MatSortModule]
   })`

in your corresponding module

Comment: What do you mean by corresponding module? and its already imported in my app.module.ts file.

Comment: Is there any reason are you creating new MatTableDataSource 
`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource( this.Result);` ?
Try using `this.dataSource=this.Result` instead.
I assume the dataSource you are pointing to paginator and sort is not same as the one you are setting in `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource( this.Result);`

Comment: initially i tried with the syntax as you pointed out, but it didn't work . So I used the syntax given by the angular-material. But it still didn't answer the question though.

Comment: Is the response getting populated in `this.Result = this.Model.log` ?

Comment: yes. I'm able to get the data and i'm successfully able ti bind the data to the grid. The only problem is with pagination and sorting

Answer (score 0):

Within the method ngOnInit, it seems you're using dataSource member that has not yet been initialized.

You can get rid of method ngOnInit and move its content down to where the webservice result is handled.

```
this.webService.CallDetails(deatails)
  .subscribe(
     response => {
        this.Model = response;
        this.Result = this.Model.log
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource( this.Result);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;        
     },
     error => console.error(error)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [angular Material Documentation on Tables here:](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Note that - this.paginator and this.sort are called - **AfterViewInit**
If you call these under onInit - this will not work.

hence, instead - call as below:

```
export class CategoriesListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  // VARIABLES
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Category>([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'icon', 'color', 'image'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private categoriesService: CategoriesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._getDataTableCategoriesData();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this._setTableAttributes();
  }

  private _getDataTableCategoriesData() {
    this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(
      (categories) => {
        this.dataSource.data = categories;
      });
  }

  private _setTableAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```